# PL/SQL ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into when using CASE

Tags: oracle, loops, plsql, case, distinct

I have the following PL/SQL Block:

```
declare
    vDayType varchar2(10);
    TYPE Holidays is table of varchar2(5);
    hd Holidays := Holidays('01.01','15.01','19.01','28.05','04.07','08.10','11.11','22.11','25.12');
begin
    for s in (select distinct saleDate from Sales) loop
        vDayType := case when TO_CHAR(s.saleDate, 'dd.mm') member of hd then 
                        'Holiday'
                    when to_char(s.saleDate, 'd') IN (1,7) then
                        'Weekend'
                    else
                        'Weekday'
                    end;
        insert into times (saleDay, dayType) values (s.saleDate, vDayType);
    end loop;
end;
/
```

This pulls data from a OLTP Table named `SALES` and inserts it into the dimension table named `TIMES`. It incorporates a `CASE` statement to "calculate" days that are Holidays, Weekdays, or Weekends. Unfortunately, when I run this code, I'm getting the following error:

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("CM420A01"."TIMES"."SALEDAY")
ORA-06512: at line 14
```

I believe it is inserting NULL because I have it set to only `SELECT DISTINCT` values from `saleDate` in the `SALES` OLTP Table. I'm assuming it's still trying to insert the `dayType` from the `CASE` statement, even when it's not inserting a `saleDay` because of the `DISTINCT` statement, which is thus inserting `NULL` into the `saleDay` column and causing the error.

Any tips/tricks to recover from this issue so it'll run without error?

Comment: I don't see how any `DISTINCT` directive can result in forcing a `NULL` anywhere. Are you sure  there is no `NULL` in the `saledate` column in table `sales`?

Comment: Boy oh Boy do I feel like an Idiot! Totally forgot that my `SALES` table had NULL dates for vehicles that were not yet sold...Added a `WHERE` clause and it's working like a champ. For some reason I wasn't thinking about the vehicles that weren't listed as `SOLD`. All good now, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added `WHERE SALES.vehicleStatus = 'sold'` clause due to `NULL` values that were being inserted for vehicles what were listed as `pending` or `available` and didn't yet have `saleDate`'s......